# MySQL/SQL Server vs. PHP encryption

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server

According to documentation, the most-secured encryption methods are:

`AES_ENCRYPT()` for MySQL

`ENCRYPTBYPASSPHRASE()` for SQL Server

`MC_ENCRYPT()` for PHP

Which one should be used?

Recently on many blogs and e-magazines is being posted information, that pre-encryption with PHP is the best way, since if the My/SQL server is compromised, the attacker can scan the logs.

Example of mcrypt pre-encrypting the string before database insertion (vs the others):

```
<?php
define('ENCRYPTION_KEY', '555d6c18e7b8aa109bfda854df942088a9984cccf2a979bd21b99e50aedc1976');

function Cryp($action, $string, $key) {
    $key = pack('H*', $key);

    if($action == 'en') {
        $string = serialize($string);
        $iv = mcrypt_create_iv(mcrypt_get_iv_size(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC), MCRYPT_DEV_URANDOM);
        $string = base64_encode(mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, $key, $string . hash_hmac('sha256', $string, substr(bin2hex($key), -32)), MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, $iv)) . '|' . base64_encode($iv);
    }

    if($action == 'de') {
        $string = explode('|', $string);
        $iv = base64_decode($string[1]);
        $string = unserialize(substr(trim(mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, $key, base64_decode($string[0]), MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, $iv)), 0, -64));
    }

    return $string;
}

$data = 'Sample string here';

$encrypted = Cryp('en', $data, ENCRYPTION_KEY);
$decrypted = Cryp('de', $encrypted, ENCRYPTION_KEY);

echo $encrypted;
?>
```

Comment: This is too broad of a question to possibly answer without having a better understanding of you application architecture and expected use cases.

Comment: It's about cardholder data storing, web/api application.

Comment: If you are planning to hold credit card data and have to ask this question, then you should really be thinking twice about that decision. Storing credit card data is not something you should be getting into unless you have a DEEP understanding of security practices. Consider using a vault service.

Comment: That is not to mention that this would likely violate you agreement with most any payment processor.  Again, you gave a one sentence description of what you want your service to do. Not enough to possibly answer this question. One needs to understand the application architecture, the use cases, the threat model, etc.

Comment: I don't see what would violate any agreements. Not to mention that "cardholder storing" was being added, just for an example of a case. The question is about self-knowledge, security is my hobby.